# Ember cli adapter set custom path for type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Is it possible to set custom url for a specific type?

For example, this is my adapter definition:

**/adapters/application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'v1',
    defaultSerializer: 'JSONSerializer',
    host: 'http://api.example.com'
});
```

No what I want is to set a custom url for a specific adapter method. By default, each request will be sent to `http://api.example.com/v1/{model}` but for the `store.query()` method for example, I would like to tell ember to request `http://api.example.com/v1/{model}/search`

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have [pathForType](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_pathForType) for the `JSONAPI` adapter

**Edit:**

This is how it works [by default](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.2.0/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/json-api-adapter.js#L109):

```
pathForType: function(modelName) {
    var dasherized = Ember.String.dasherize(modelName);
    return Ember.String.pluralize(dasherized);
  },
```

You receive the name of the model and you can return a different url.

But, since you want to specify a different url depending on a method, you should use [`buildURL`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.2.0/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/build-url-mixin.js):

```
buildURL: function(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {
    switch (requestType) {
      case 'findRecord':
        return this.urlForFindRecord(id, modelName, snapshot);
      case 'findAll':
        return this.urlForFindAll(modelName);
      case 'query':
        return this.urlForQuery(query, modelName);
      case 'queryRecord':
        return this.urlForQueryRecord(query, modelName);
      case 'findMany':
        return this.urlForFindMany(id, modelName, snapshot);
      case 'findHasMany':
        return this.urlForFindHasMany(id, modelName);
      case 'findBelongsTo':
        return this.urlForFindBelongsTo(id, modelName);
      case 'createRecord':
        return this.urlForCreateRecord(modelName, snapshot);
      case 'updateRecord':
        return this.urlForUpdateRecord(id, modelName, snapshot);
      case 'deleteRecord':
        return this.urlForDeleteRecord(id, modelName, snapshot);
      default:
        return this._buildURL(modelName, id);
    }
  },
```

Comment: A hint on how to use it? It takes a model as parameter. How does it allow me to set custom url for the `store.query()` method?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm playing with right now, however, is it possible to override only `case: 'query'` then call some kind of `super()` method from the base class? I have tried calling `this._super()` and I'm given an error. thank you.

Comment: Yes, `Error while processing route: index Unexpected token < SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: Are you sure the error is there? Could you show the change you have made to `buildURL`?

Comment: Yes, the error is from there because if I comment it out then the error is gone. About changes, I did not change anything https://gist.github.com/teckays/9a14f49b15fc951c4298

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96059/discussion-between-andrei-stalbe-and-henry-vonfire).